# Negotiating an allocator between Directshow filters fails

Tags: directshow

I'm developing a custom Directshow source filter to provide decompressed video data to a rendering filter. I've used the PushSource sample provided by the Directshow SDK as a basis for my filter. I'm attempting to connect this to a VideoMixingRenderer9 filter.

When creating the graph I'm calling ConnectDirect():

```
HRESULT hr = mp_graph_builder->ConnectDirect(OutPin, InPin, &mediaType);
```

but during this call, calling SetProperties on the downstream filters allocator (in DecideBufferSize()), fails with D3DERR_INVALIDCALL (0x8876086c):

```
ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES actual;
memset(&actual,0,sizeof(actual));
hr = pAlloc->SetProperties(pRequest, &actual);
```

If I let it try to use my allocator (the one provided by CBaseOutputPin) when setting the allocator on the downstream filter, this fails with E_FAIL (in CBaseOutputPin::DecideAllocator)

```
hr = pPin->NotifyAllocator(*ppAlloc, FALSE);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks.

EDIT:
This is the media type provided by GetMediaType

```
VIDEOINFOHEADER *pvi = (VIDEOINFOHEADER*)pMediaType->AllocFormatBuffer(sizeof(VIDEOINFOHEADER));
if (pvi == 0) 
    return(E_OUTOFMEMORY);

ZeroMemory(pvi, pMediaType->cbFormat);   
pvi->AvgTimePerFrame = m_rtFrameLength;

pMediaType->formattype = FORMAT_VideoInfo; 
pMediaType->majortype = MEDIATYPE_Video;
pMediaType->subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24; 
pMediaType->bTemporalCompression = FALSE;
pMediaType->bFixedSizeSamples = TRUE;
pMediaType->formattype = FORMAT_VideoInfo;
pvi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
pvi->bmiHeader.biWidth = (640 / 128 + 1) * 128;
pvi->bmiHeader.biHeight = -480; // negative so top down..
pvi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
pvi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
pvi->bmiHeader.biCompression = NULL; // ok if rgb else use MAKEFOURCC(...)
pvi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage  = GetBitmapSize(&pvi->bmiHeader);
pvi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
pvi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed    = 0;        //Use max colour depth
pvi->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0; 
pvi->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
SetRectEmpty(&(pvi->rcSource));
SetRectEmpty(&(pvi->rcTarget));
pvi->rcSource.bottom = 480;
pvi->rcSource.right = 640;
pvi->rcTarget.bottom = 480;
pvi->rcTarget.right = 640;

pMediaType->SetType(&MEDIATYPE_Video);
pMediaType->SetFormatType(&FORMAT_VideoInfo);
pMediaType->SetTemporalCompression(FALSE);
const GUID SubTypeGUID = GetBitmapSubtype(&pvi->bmiHeader);
pMediaType->SetSubtype(&SubTypeGUID);
pMediaType->SetSampleSize(pvi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
```

and DecideBufferSize where pAlloc->SetProperties is called

```
HRESULT CPushPinBitmap::DecideBufferSize(IMemAllocator *pAlloc, ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES *pRequest) {
    HRESULT hr;
    CAutoLock cAutoLock(CBasePin::m_pLock);

    CheckPointer(pAlloc, E_POINTER);
    CheckPointer(pRequest, E_POINTER);

    if (pRequest->cBuffers == 0) {
        pRequest->cBuffers = 2;
    }
    pRequest->cbBuffer =  480 * ( (640 / 128 + 1) * 128 ) * 3;

    ALLOCATOR_PROPERTIES actual;
    memset(&actual,0,sizeof(actual));
    hr = pAlloc->SetProperties(pRequest, &actual);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        return hr;
    }
    if (actual.cbBuffer < pRequest->cbBuffer) {
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

The constants are only temporary!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can use your own allocator with VMR/EVR filters. They just insist on their own, which in turn is backed on DirectDraw/Direct3D surfaces.

To connect directly to VMR/EVR filters you need a different strategy. The allocator is always theirs. You need to support extended strides. See [Handling Format Changes from the Video Renderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to use the VMR allocator, if it will let me. The VMR filter is calling QueryAccept during the call to SetProperties, and QueryAccept is returning S_OK. I believe I'm setting the stride correctly (in GetMediaType - ((width / 128) + 1) * 128 ). Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: You normally provide a media type with default stride, and VMR would update the stride and notify you via dynamic format change. What exactly is the error when you are using VMR's allcoator?

Comment: I'm setting the stride originally in GetMediaType (pMediaType->pbFormat->bmiHeader.biWidth). When VMR calls CheckMediaType (via QueryAccept) it provides the same value. I'm not sure what happens between that returning S_OK and SetProperties returning D3DERR_INVALIDCALL.

Comment: Will you update your post with full details on current connection media type, and arguments to `SetProperties` call?

Comment: Done. VMR is happily accepting the media type initially, but fails at SetProperties.

Comment: OK, well now what is your 128 is all about? The standard stride is the required number of bytes + padding to 32-bit boundary. There is no 128 there. As you have 24-bit RGB, `cbBuffer` has to be `((3 * width) + 3) / 4 * 4`.

Comment: Thanks Roman. I've also had to change to 32-bit RGB (it seems VMR9 only accepts RGB at the same bit depth as the display in the initial exchange!). VMR is now at least accepting the allocator seetings.

Comment: It accepts this initial configuration and will run with it, or it will propose extended stride. The latter takes place already on runtime, as soon as you start streaming.